# ImageMagnifier как добавить рамку

Tags: android, android-canvas

Есть ImageMagnifier, который представляет собой "лупу" для ImageView:

```
public class ImageMagnifier extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    private PointF zoomPos;
    private boolean zooming = false;
    private Matrix matrix;
    private Paint paint;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private BitmapShader shader;
    private int sizeOfMagnifier = 200;

    public ImageMagnifier(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ImageMagnifier(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public ImageMagnifier(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        zoomPos = new PointF(0, 0);
        matrix = new Matrix();
        paint = new Paint();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        zoomPos.x = event.getX();
        zoomPos.y = event.getY();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                zooming = true;
                this.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                zooming = false;
                this.invalidate();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (!zooming) {
            buildDrawingCache();
        } else {

            bitmap = getDrawingCache();
            shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setShader(shader);

            matrix.reset();
            matrix.postScale(2f, 2f, zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y);
            paint.getShader().setLocalMatrix(matrix);
            canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y - 150, sizeOfMagnifier, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Работает всё корректно, только не знаю как можно добавить рамку для лупы. Пытался сделать что-то вроде:

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Но в таком случае получается инверсия: увеличенное изображение отображается в рамке(которая должна быть черной), а сама лупа пустая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ход мыслей у вас был верный, только для рамки, нужно создать отдельный объект `Pain` и рисовать её после отрисовки самой лупы:

```
...
canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y-150, sizeOfMagnifier, paint);

Paint border = new Paint();
border.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
border.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y - 150, sizeOfMagnifier, border);
```

Только вы должны избегать создания новых объектов в методе `onDraw`, о чём вам вероятно уже подсказывала Android Studio. То есть создайте объёкты `Paint` при инициализации вью, а в `onDraw`, просто переиспользуйте их.